# Taylor Polynomials, Why only Integer Powers?

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion

So It seems that the definition of polynomial is that is is raised to an integer power, but why is this necessary? My question mainly arises from a proof of the solution to the Hydrogen atom in quantum mechanics, where they rely on the fact that the terminating term in series expansion of a function is an integer power. I know that Taylor series work without the need for decimal and fractional powers, but why not use them? Would it not work? Why are polynomials defined as only have integer powers, and why are decimal powers subpar?

Comment: The purpose of math is to make life easier. One traditional way to do this is to approximate complicated things by things that are easier to understand. Polynomials with integer powers are easy to understand, so we use them. What is wonderful is that you don't need anything more complicated than integer powers to get Taylor series to work.

Comment: Polynomials **must** have positive integer powers in the varialbe *by definition*. This is beyond ease or difficulty.

Comment: Another reason is that powers of the form $a^b$, where $b$ is not an integer, are not well defined for all values of $a$. For example, $(-1)^{\frac 14}$ is not well-defined: not only is there no real number $x$ such that $x^4=-1$, but there are four different complex numbers that *do* satisfy that equation - and there's no reason to prefer any of them over the others.

Comment: On the other hand, [Puiseux series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) have a formidable history and have been used, among others, by those studying algebraic curves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polynomials are actually restricted to only have *natural* exponents, not integer. The importance of polynomials is that they form a large class of functions that we can actually compute precisely (given the accuracy of the coefficients) on any input (depending on the accuracy of the input). Functions we can compute are important and we like them, and that is why they are studied. If you can express something as a polynomial then you probably should do it. Of course, we can, and and do, define other kinds of functions. There is nothing bad about them, it's just they may not be polynomials.

Now, when we are given a function that is not a polynomial, we might wish to approximate it by the simplest thing we can think of - a polynomial. Taylor polynomials do just that. They relate a function and its derivative (and of course repeated derivatives of a function can only be taken a number of times, counted by a natural number (though fractional derivatives exist)) to a polynomial. That polynomial may or may not approximate the function, depending on the function, but it's a start. If it works, then that's great. If it does not, then you look for other solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @Shub, can you be more precise about what you think is inaccurate?

Comment: I think you meant *whole number exponent* instead of *natural exponents*.

Comment: No, in a polynomial only natural numbers may appear as exponents, not all whole numbers.