# Why must power series count up by integers 0,1,2.. in 3D harmonic oscillator in spherical coordinates?

Tags: spherical-coordinates, quantum-mechanics

http://www.physicspages.com/2013/01/17/harmonic-oscillator-in-3-d-spherical-coordinates/
http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node244.html

These are two links that have roughly the same proof
of the energy levels of a 3-D harmonic oscillator, using
spherical coordinates.  The proofs use a step where the
function is expressed as a power series.  The fact that
that power series counts up by integers 0,1,2..  produces
the fact that the energy levels are quantized with values
hω(n + l + 3/2).

Why couldn't you define the power series to count up by
0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, ..   or some other weird method
and then come up with a result of different energy levels?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method

Comment: Well, that link and reading about Taylor series says that indeed any function  "satisfying certain conditions"  is guaranteed to be representable by a power series, which is reassuring.  I see that there is also a similar question posted before:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579783/taylor-polynomials-why-only-integer-powers --- Still, this leaves the question of why would we not use an expansion like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series.

Comment: And if we did, would we not get a different result thus invalidating the quantum mechanical belief that the energy levels follow the formula hω(n + l + 3/2).

Comment: You can index a sum on any totally ordered countable set. If you notice, in those articles the indices also appear in the terms of the sum, not just as, well... indices. This means that when you re-index the sums on a different set you must change the terms, too, and the resulting value will be the same. It would be quite upsetting if the result of a sum depended on how you count the summands...

Comment: There are uniqueness theorems for solutions to ODEs, which apply in this context, so however we find a solution, it's the correct solution. This means that the solutions obtained with the Method of Frobenius are actually the only ones.

Comment: Now THAT is very reassuring  (that we know that the  "integer power series"  solutions are the only solution).  Thanks for pointing that out - if I had read the Frobenius link closely I'm sure it would have come out.  I guess A.P. is saying the same thing although somehow I feel more reassured knowing that there is some proof that one can just say  "The integer counting solution is the only one."

Comment: I wouldn't say "the integer counting solution is the only one" because it seems to suggest that the only way to get a solution is to use integer-indexed power series. I would rather say something like "there is a unique solution, which can be computed using integer-indexed power series."

Comment: Point taken;  thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chappers basically answered it by linking to the Frobenius method.

A.P. and Chappers further clarify why one need not worry
that there are other lurking solutions that would only
uncover if you expanded to think about alternate indicing
representation.